# can xbee as router scan all end device with "ATAS active scan command"? or Are there another way?

Tags: xbee, rssi, zigbee

If i buy 7 xbee-zigbee. I setup xbee modules like this.

```
1 coordinator (C)
3 router (R1-R2 -R3)
3 end device (ED1 - ED2 - ED3)
```

Can a router scan all end device with "AS" (active scan) command?
Result must be like this;

```
R1 get rssi value from ED1 : -90 dbm
R1 get rssi value from ED2 : -60 dbm
R1 get rssi value from ED3 : -80 dbm​

R2 get rssi value from ED1 : -40 dbm
R2 get rssi value from ED2 : -55 dbm
R2 get rssi value from ED3 : -89 dbm​

R3 get rssi value from ED1 : -23 dbm
R3 get rssi value from ED2 : -10 dbm
R3 get rssi value from ED3 : -70 dbm​
```

Is this possible? Or is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

Devices will only respond to a Beacon Request (Active Scan) if they are in the "RX on when idle" configuration.  This mostly means Routers (and the Coordinator).

There are a few different types of End Device.  If they indicates in their Device Announce message that they are "RX on when idle" then they should respond to Beacon Requests.  Very few devices actually work this way (a few light bulbs).  Most End Devices are battery powered and will not respond to Beacon Requests because they aren't on to hear them.

Answer (score 0):

The `ATAS` command was designed for network discovery, and you use it when you aren't connected to an active network.  The XBee module will scan multiple channels for networks and dump information on each beacon it receives on those channels.  Since you can't join a network through an end device, you're not going to see beacons coming from those devices.

You might be more interested in exploring the `ATND` (Node Discovery) command, for getting a list of devices on the current network.

Answer (score 0):

Mvut from digi said this:"you can use the S2C ZB module and use the ZDO commands to report the Link status." Any body try this?

Answer (score 0):

you can try API mode  , it can sent Remote AT command(0x17) and sent back response(0x97) .
something like:

```
7E 00 0F 17 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF FF FF FF 02 64 62 23
0x7E - package start 
0x00、0x0F  - package length
0x17 - frame type
0x01   - ! this byte is important about if you want to get the response or not
...
```

I hope it can help for you~